# Formula that will search cells in table to find a word

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula, cell, worksheet-function

I'm looking for a formula that will allow me to look for a value in a table and return any information if the value exists. Either True/False or a number where it starts (like search formula).

The problem is that I will be looking for a word `Apple` and in the table there might be like:

Column A

- Orange
- Apple, grapefruit
- Peach, tomato, carrot
- Potato
- etc.

So everything is in one column but there might be more than one value in one cell.
The values do not repeat. So in the table there will be only one `Apple`.

Is there any way to do this with a formula?

Comment: Have you tried using `VLOOKUP` or `MATCH`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MATCH](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-gb/article/MATCH-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca?CorrelationId=433658f2-bb2f-4e83-8165-2f502a1f5844&ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB) allows wildcards, so:

```
=MATCH("*Apple*",A:A,0)
```

should return the row number in which `Apple` is in a cell in ColumnA. If more than one instance will return only the first.

Comment: It worked! Thank you. I didn't know about the wildcards before. 
Just to add for the future. If somebody want to use it with cell reference it will be "*"&A1&"*"